# Syntax error in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

Why am I getting an invalid syntax error for these statements for Creating the folder for specific Employee ID training images if it doesn't exist?

## Capture images

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = []
    camera = config.get_camera()

    # Create the directory for positive training images if it doesn't exist.
    if not os.path.exists(config.Subject_Dir):
       os.makedirs(config.Subject_Dir)
       foldername = os.path.join(config.Subject_Dir, Filename + '%03d' % (config.Subject_Id)

    # Create the folder for specific Employee ID training images if it doesn't exist.
    if not os.path.exists(foldername):
        os.path.makedirs(foldername)

    # Find the largest ID of existing images.
    # Start new images after this ID value.        
    files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(foldername,'[0-9][0-9][0-9]' + '.pgm')))
    count = 0
```

Comment: Show us more code. You sure syntax error is in these lines?

Comment: Hey, I've added that part of the code, could you please help me out?

Comment: Please add the actual Traceback to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting syntax error, because in the line

```
foldername = os.path.join(config.Subject_Dir, Filename + '%03d' % (config.Subject_Id)
```

you didn't close the first parenthesis. Just add `)` to the end of the line, like this:

```
foldername = os.path.join(config.Subject_Dir, Filename + '%03d' % (config.Subject_Id))
```